# What's the proper use of mailaddress and mail-address tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was about to merge the [mailaddress](/questions/tagged/mailaddress) and [mail-address](/questions/tagged/mail-address) as per

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135985/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags

but I realized that these two tags are used with two very different meanings.

The [mailaddress](/questions/tagged/mailaddress) tag is mainly used to refer to the `MailAddress` class in `.NET`. (6 out of 7 questions) and in one case is used to refer to an physical address location.

On the other hand [mail-address](/questions/tagged/mail-address) is used to refer to a physical address, typically in the context of forward/reverse geocoding.

Given this I think the two tags should be removed by the list of tags to be merged posted in  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135985/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags.

Am I correct?

Also should we "formalize" this distinction with appropriate tag descriptions? Or are the two tags invalid somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Leave them alone" is never a good option. If you have two tags that only differ by a hyphen, *something* needs to be done.

As for the [mail-address](/questions/tagged/mail-address) tag, there's already a [street-address](/questions/tagged/street-address) tag which makes more sense, has a larger base of questions, and actually has a tag wiki and excerpt. Let's send those questions over to that tag.

I don't see any reason to get rid of the .NET-specific tag, but it does need a quick wiki excerpt so that people can see it's meant to be about .NET and not street addresses.

All done. :)

Comment: awesome, thank you! For the sake of completeness I removed the two tags from the long list linked in my question. One less to go ;)